# Node streams: remote stream is returning JSON, but on('data') shows buffer

Tags: json, node.js, stream, buffer

I'm just starting out with [Node stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)s.

My library's demo code uses:

```
stream.pipe(process.stdout, {end: true});
```

Which works fine, printing chunks of JSON to standard output.

I'd like to use:

```
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk)
}
```

But I get a binary buffer instead:

```
chunk! <Buffer 7b 22 73 74 72 65 61 6d 22 3a 22 20 2d 2d 2d 5c 75 30 30 33 65 20 35 35 32 38 38 36 39 62 30 30 33 37 5c 6e 22 7d>
```

Is there a way I can use on('data') and see the JSON?

Comment: `chunk.toString('utf8')`

Comment: @JoshC. That worked perfectly (`JSON.parse(chunk.toString('utf8'))` specifically). Change the comment to an answer and I'll tick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should run `stream.setEncoding('utf8')` on your stream, so node.js core will decode utf8 automatically.

You should probably **not** use `chunk.toString('utf8')` like suggested earlier because it can garble unicode characters on the boundaries, unless you're sure that the data will be in one block.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chunck.toString ('utf8')`. Also, the `Buffer` class has other encodings too!